# Rename wget downloaded parent dir

Tags: linux, wget

I use this command to download the entire wikipedia content of main page :

```
wget -p -k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

But I receive an error when try to combine it with -O in order to rename the downloaded parent dir :

wget -p -k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page `-O` mydir

```
Cannot specify both -k or --convert-file-only and -O if multiple URLs are given, or in combination
with -p or -r. See the manual for details.
```

How to download the URL entirely and name the downloaded parent dir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
mkdir mydir && chdir mydir && \
    wget -p -k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

or

```
wget -p -k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
mv -Tf en.wikipedia.org mydir
```

Depending on where exactly you want it

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-O` option without  combination with `-k` :

```
wget https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page -O mydir
```

**Edit**

Use `-P` option and specify the directory:

```
 wget -P /path/to/mydir -k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page/
```

Example

```
wget -P mydir -k https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page/
```

Comment: thanks but that does not grab all content of the page.